# Search data from json value in sql

Tags: postgresql

We have following data in **details** column for one of the table:

```
{"_translated": {"en_GB": {"name": "Bathroom 2", "description": "Bathroom 2"}, "en_US": {"name": "Bathroom 2", "description": "Bathroom 2"}, "es_ES": {"name": "Baño 2", "description": "Baño 2"}, "es_MX": {"name": "Baño 2", "description": "Baño 2"}, "fr_FR": {"name": "Salle de bain 2", "description": "Salle de bain 2"}, "hi_IN": {"name": "स्नानघर 2", "description": "स्नानघर 2"}, "zh_CN": {"name": "浴室 2", "description": "浴室 2"}, "en_GB.machine": {"name": "Bathroom 2", "description": "Bathroom 2"}, "es_MX.machine": {"name": "Baño 2", "description": "Baño 2"}, "field_locales": {"name": "en_US", "description": "en_US"}, "hi_IN.machine": {"name": "स्नानघर 2", "description": "स्नानघर 2"}, "zh_CN.machine": {"name": "浴室2", "description": "浴室2"}, "default_locale": "en_US"}}

{"_translated": {"en_GB": {"name": "Office", "description": "Office"}, "en_US": {"name": "Office", "description": "Office"}, "es_ES": {"name": "Oficina", "description": "Oficina"}, "es_MX": {"name": "Oficina", "description": "Oficina"}, "fr_FR": {"name": "Bureau", "description": "Bureau"}, "hi_IN": {"name": "कार्यालय", "description": "कार्यालय"}, "zh_CN": {"name": "办公室", "description": "办公室"}, "es_MX.machine": {"name": "Oficina", "description": "Oficina"}, "field_locales": {"name": "en_US", "description": "en_US"}, "hi_IN.machine": {"name": "कार्यालय", "description": "कार्यालय"}, "zh_CN.machine": {"name": "办公室", "description": "办公室"}, "default_locale": "en_US"}}

{"_translated": {"en_GB": {"name": "Bedroom 2", "description": "Bedroom 2"}, "en_US": {"name": "Bedroom 2", "description": "Bedroom 2"}, "es_ES": {"name": "Habitación 2", "description": "Habitación 2"}, "es_MX": {"name": "Habitación 2", "description": "Habitación 2"}, "fr_FR": {"name": "Chambre 2", "description": "Chambre 2"}, "hi_IN": {"name": "शयनकक्ष 2", "description": "शयनकक्ष 2"}, "zh_CN": {"name": "卧室 2", "description": "卧室 2"}, "es_MX.machine": {"name": "Dormitorio 2", "description": "Dormitorio 2"}, "field_locales": {"name": "en_US", "description": "en_US"}, "hi_IN.machine": {"name": "शयनकक्ष 2", "description": "शयनकक्ष 2"}, "zh_CN.machine": {"name": "卧室2", "description": "卧室2"}, "default_locale": "es_ES"}}
```

Now I want to find all those records having "default_locale": "en_US" and those records for which its not present in translated.

```
SELECT details FROM locations where details->'default_locale' = 'es_ES';
```

But this not works. Any help appreciated.

Comment: "But this not works." is not a useful description of a problem. Do you get an error message? Unwanted result? Be specific! Though part of the solution surely is to search for `'en_US'` when you want en_US, not `'es_ES'`. Also [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Side note: The schema of the JSON looks pretty static to me. You should consider not to abuse JSON but use relational means like (lookup and/or linking) tables and columns instead.

Comment: Do you get any error message or no results? At first glance it seems that your are looking for `default_locale` on root level but it's nested in the `_translated` object so it should be something like `details->'_translated'->'default_locale' = 'es_ES'`.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT details
 FROM locations
WHERE details -> '_translated' ->> 'default_locale' = 'en_US' 
   OR details -> '_translated' ->> 'default_locale' is null;
```

Not related, but as @stickybit pointed above - review your data design. Having to search/filter by JSON attribute values is not a good symptom at all.